# How can i check that app is installed with my link or not or cancelled?

Tags: java, android

I want to to list some play store app links in my app. and i want that user click on the link and go to the play store and download the app. Now i want to track that if user clicked on the link and has he downloaded or not the app or not cancelled the download. so how can i implement this kind if feature in android studio.

Comment: `and has he downloaded or not the app or not cancelled the download` I'm not sure if its possible to get information about third party apps on the play store. If the linked apps are your own, then maybe you can use Firebase to track your own app's downloads etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using package manager you can check whether app installed or not

```
if(appInstalledOrNot(com.demo.package)){
    Toast.makeText(this,"App Installed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this,"App NOt Installed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String packageName) {  
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("::MG::",""+e);
        return false;
    } 
}
```

- you can call this function onResume so when user come back to application from play-store you check application status is installed or not.